# Remembering last checked parent category in Term Reference Tree

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a lot of categories using [Term Reference Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) that start minimized. I want it to remember the last category, subcategory, and term checked. Is this possible?

I think it needs JS code and a custom database table for every user's last addition that contains the last three checked terms. Please if you know how to solve this help me.

Comment: it does not needs to remember in my own table the last checked terms, cause I can get it from te last node added by user. So the task is: how to get the last checked term and how to open parents categories when user add new node ?